# How to make chef run all the recipes in a cookbook without explicitly listing each one?

Tags: chef-infra

Is there a way to tell a chef node to run all the recipe files in a cookbook without having to manually add each one to the runlist or perform some other manual task from the workstation?

I suspect that there may be a way to query the list of available recipes at chef-client execution time, but I don't know what the ruby command/syntax would be.

Comment: Directory listing saved to a file? Try `find /recipes/directory -type f -maxdepth 1 >> runlist.file` or whatever is appropriate for chef.

Comment: First idea coming to my mind is to create a script which will add include_recipes into the default recipe for each recipe of the cookbook. in a 'bash' way: `for f in \`ls -I default.rb -1\`; do echo "include_recipe 'cookbook::$f'"; done > default.rb` This mean default recipe should have only these inclusions, if you have code in ti, move it to anotehr recipe. (But that sounds a bad pattern)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing in particular for this that wouldn't be touching many internal APIs. It probably means that you have too many recipes in the cookbook though. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Followed up with the user via IRC and they declined further help.

Comment: I appreciate the effort, I really do.  Please don't read any ingratitude into my response.  Your eagerness to help absolutely makes this world and this community a better place.  
It's just that really all I wanted was to get a focused answer to the question I was asking.  To give you all the details of my organization and infrastructure and workflow so you can analyze my problem for me is more involved than I'm looking to get into.  
If no "yes" answers come in after a while I'll mark this "no" answer as correct.

Comment: When someone asks to "break the rules" of API boundaries I need to know that this is truly the right solution before I hand them that code. To do otherwise would be irresponsibly exposing people to Chef's internals. For example, I can give you a Ruby one-liner to do this, and I can _promise_ it will break in Chef 13 because I'm the one planning to break it when we change the cookbook file data format in memory. If you want the simple answer then no, you can't do this. If you want the true answer, you need to make sure you want to dive into the deep end.

Comment: understood.  I'm not soliciting unsupported hacks that are going to break in the future.  Honestly I just don't know what is or is not supported.  Beyond what's available at https://docs.chef.io/recipes.html, it's not really clear what's available (or forbidden) to you when writing recipes.  Where are these API boundaries defined?

Comment: Since we're on the subject, and if it is a simple one liner, is there a reason why making this a feature would be a bad idea?  Like a run_list entry that looks like recipe[my_cookbook::*] or something?

Comment: It isn't a specific feature because no one has ever argued for it. You could file an RFC if you wanted to write up :) I don't think it would be useful to enough people to justify inclusion in core though, but if you could show the patch as being small enough then it might not hurt anything.

Comment: Also re: API boundaries, they are fuzzy. The Chef advisory board actually just requested that the maintainers take some time to lay out what is internal and what isn't for exactly this reason. Even with that, I don't think the cookbook collection data would be a public API.

Answer (score 0):

add below line in default recipe (default.rb) of your cookbook.

```
include_recipe "cookbook::recipe"
```

Include all recipes like that and 
now run chef client by adding only cookbook name to the runlist (don't mention recipes or you can mention default recipe. either way it'll work)